# Bitmap Factory doesn't show image in ImageView

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I am making a simple app in which I am using Firebase to upload pictures on firebase storage. The uploading works fine. When I try to download the uploaded picture in some other part of the app with map fragment, the image doesn't show. However, if I try to download and show image in activity without maps, the image shows just fine.

Code I am using for retrieving pictures

```
try {
            final File tmpFile = File.createTempFile("img", "png");
            sreference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("photos");

            sreference.child("my").getFile(tmpFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    Bitmap pic = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tmpFile.getAbsolutePath());

                    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1) {
                        pic = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pic, fixerpic.getWidth(),fixerpic.getHeight(),true);
                    }
                    fixerpic.setImageBitmap(pic);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

xml layout for activity where image doesn't show:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:layout_margin="0dp">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="digiart.mapwithfirebase.MapsActivity" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_weight="0.85">

        <ImageView    << This imageview
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@id/fixerimage"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="NAME"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                android:id="@+id/fixer_name"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/call"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:onClick="makecall"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/message"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:onClick="sendmessage"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/favbtn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/favourite"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:onClick="favourite"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/map_progbar"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

xml layout in the activity where image is showing properly

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/bggradient2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Select Image"
            android:onClick="selectimage"/>

        <ImageView     << This imageview
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/image"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kindly Fill Your Correct Details"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"/>


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/reg_fixer_name"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:hint="Full Name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/register_fixer_phone"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:hint="Phone Number"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Your Location: _________"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/locationshowtxt"/>

        <Button

            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corner_white"
            android:text="Get My Location First"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/orange"
            android:onClick="getlocation"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select Your Expertise From Dopdown below"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corner_white"
            android:id="@+id/dropdown">
        </Spinner>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/register_userbtn"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corner_white"
            android:text="Register"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:onClick="register_fixer_btn"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/reg_fixer_progbar"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use download service mention in this link https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/storage

Comment: `File tmpFile = File.createTempFile("img", "png");`.  Yopu cannot use the File class like that. You should use absoluthe paths. Please tell the value of `tmpFile.getAbsolutePath()`.

Comment: `addOnSuccessListener()` OK. But where is the on fail listener?

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }`. You are shure you have no exceptions? Put a log statement in it and a Toast() so you and the user know what happens.

Comment: And how do you know if onSuccess() is ever called? I see no Log.d() statements or Toasts.